# How to use velodye-64 with velodyne driver

Tags: ros, driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch calibration:=/home/user/32db.yaml

how to revamp it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264113/how-to-use-velodye-64-with-velodyne-driver/) by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The driver is [documented on the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver?distro=kinetic).

There is not a launch file for the 64e models that exactly duplicates `32e_points.launch`. I suggest that you make a copy of that script and update its parameters following the documentation above.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0